# Simplifying the soda gun mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design

I'm looking to design a push button mechanism similar to the soda gun where water is forced to pass through a single passage based on which button has been pressed. What are the different approaches I can take to solving this problem? This is a purely mechanical design problem, without the aid of electricity.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked for valves?

Comment: @EricS If the water was already flowing and I pressed a button to change the output pipe, wouldn't I have to overcome the force of the flowing water with a valve? I don't know of a way to easily translate the little force required from a button press to significantly moving a valve to position.

Comment: Levers come to mind.

Comment: Perhaps you should define what you mean by “soda gun”

Comment: I would be *amazed* if the common design of soda gun isn't already about as simple as possible - it's had decades of value engineering